# Why materials only apply when i click on Use Nodes?

Tags: materials

Why materials only apply when i click on Use Nodes?

This doesn't work
[image]

This does
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're in *Solid* shading mode which doesn't support node-based materials.
Switch to *Material Preview* or *Rendered preview* and nodes will work properly.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for helping me out!